# How to fix Jest tests that are throwing "Cannot find module" error?

Tags: jestjs

I’d appreciate some advice for an error I am running into while running Jest tests.

The code I am running can be found here as I am working on Mozilla’s Devtools:

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file

I have added an import statement to the file devtools/client/debugger/src/components/Editor/SearchBar.js. The file is here:  
https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/devtools/client/debugger/src/components/Editor/SearchBar.js

The import statement is:

import { PluralForm } from "devtools/shared/plural-form";

I use this function in my code change. For some reason this is creating errors in the tests "Editor.spec.js" and "SearchBar.spec.js".

Tests can be found here: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/devtools/client/debugger/src/components/Editor/tests

The error is: Cannot find module 'devtools/shared/plural-form' from 'SearchBar.js'

The function works perfectly fine when I run the code, but Jest is having a hard time resolving the module.

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried adding  to modulePaths in the config file.

Cannot find module 'devtools/shared/plural-form' from 'SearchBar.js'

```
  37 | import type SourceEditor from "../../utils/editor/source-editor";
  38 | 
> 39 | const { PluralForm } = require("devtools/shared/plural-form");
     |                        ^
  40 | // import { PluralForm } from "devtools/shared/plural-form";
  41 | 
  42 | function getShortcuts() {

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Editor/SearchBar.js:39:24)
```